# Easiest way to make a list

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers

After doing some searches, it seemed as if:

```
repeated type thislist = 1;
```

Should make a list, but I'm getting this error:

> cannot convert from 'Google.Protobuf.Collections.RepeatedField' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the resource where you got that line of code that says it should make a list?

Comment: It implements `IList` and `IList<T>`, not derives from concrete class `List`. (see https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/csharp/class/google/protobuf/collections/repeated-field-t-)

Comment: I think this is what I checked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3065993/whats-the-proto-equivalent-of-listt-in-protobuf-net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to assume you're using the Google implementation, in which case what you get is a *type* of list (an `IList<T>`) without being a `List<T>`.

If you *want* simple idiomatic types, protobuf-net may be more your style; [you can see the difference here](https://protogen.marcgravell.com/?names=original#g4c6ad7aff1404e46cc3aed0f77d15f78) (click "generate", and change the tooling between `(protogen) C#` and `(protoc) C#` - protogen (protobuf-net) gives:

```
[global::ProtoBuf.ProtoMember(1)]
public global::System.Collections.Generic.List<type> thislist { get; }
    = new global::System.Collections.Generic.List<type>();
```

where-as protoc (Google) gives:

```
[global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute]
public pbc::RepeatedField<global::type> Thislist {
    get { return thislist_; }
```